# Using Selenium without Firebug?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, firebug

I am installing Selenium right now and tutorials say, that i need Firebug.
Unfortunnally on the download page (https://getfirebug.com/) it says:

> The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer.
>   We invite you to use the Firefox DevTools instead, which ship with
>   Firebug.next

Does it mean that i have to use Firefox DevTools to run Selenium now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't always need firebug. Right clicking an element in firefox or chrome will provide you with an option to inspect an element. From there you can right click on the HTML to copy the xpath and CSS, as well as see an element's ID, name, class etc. The tools can be found by pressing ctrl+shift+i in both chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 3):

selenium not dependent on firebug. firebug is a tool to inspect element on page to help you get the CSS locator or xpath  which used in selenium script to find element from page. now you can use the devtool to inspect element, like chrome's devtool.

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium, you don't need these tools but if you still want to you FIREBUG and FIREPATH Extensions then do one thing Install FIREFOX version `45` or below and uncheck the Automatic Update in Firefox.

Keep in mind as soon as you update the firefox these extensions will stop working 
You can find details to stop automatic update on below link
https://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-automatic-updates-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

For selenium I use firefox 58. Firebug 2.0.19 is only compatible with Firefox 30 – 54.  That's why I use the Mozilla Firefox ESR, Portable Edition 52.6.0 and Firebug to inspect elements. https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox-portable-esr